# Add a new configuration link in Plone Site setup

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I want a new link in Site Setup. How can I add an external link in Site Setup (`@@plone_control_panel`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it through ZMI, accessing `portal_controlpanel` tool.

At the bottom you have a form for adding new items:

- Name: user friendly name
- Id: choose one, unique and with no spaces or other special chars
- Action: is your URL. If you need an expernal link type `string:http://something.com/`
- Category: this controls if you link will be in the Plone native section above or in the add-ons section below
- Visible: put true

There's other options, but they are only needed if you need some special security check or want an icon (copy from other already defined actions in that case).